# Preventing rerenders with React.memo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, create-react-app, react-usememo

I have built a web app where users have profiles with different pages. In all the pages there is a profile picture and a banner and I want them to be rendered only once.

Now, every time the user changes the page the profile picture and banner are refreshed. I want to stop this.

**How it works now:**

[image: How it works now]

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

I have been playing with React.memo but I can't make it work.

Every parent page (Presets, Store and Courses) fetch all the data (profile picture, banner...).

And then I pass the data to the child component Banner and ProfilePicture.

This is my **Banner component** code (the banner prop is an url type string):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap";

const Banner = ({banner}) => {

const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
const breakpoint = 620;


useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setWidth(window.innerWidth));
},[])

return ( 
    <>
        <Container style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
            <Row>
                <Col className="pl-0 pr-0">
                    {width < breakpoint ?
                        <div
                        style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${banner})`,
                            backgroundSize: "cover",
                            backgroundPosition: "center center",
                            height: "40vw",
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                        }}
                        className="justify-content-center"
                        >
                        
                        </div>
                    :    
                        <div
                        style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${banner})`,
                            backgroundSize: "cover",
                            backgroundPosition: "center center",
                            height: "25vw",
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                        }}
                        className="justify-content-center"
                        >
                        
                        </div>
                    }
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </>
 );
}

export default React.memo(Banner);
```

And in the **parent components** (All the pages) I fetch the data and I pass it to the banner component like this:

```
<Banner banner={banner}/>
```

I think banner is first undefined and then is the fetched url so the props change every time from undefined to string and thats why React memo is not working.

And I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: How many times do you render Banner component. Is it present in each parent component? If so, it will be rendered every time you swap the parent component. 
If you want to render it only once, you will have to pull it out to a root component, which renders the Presets, Store and Courses, and render it there once. Then the memo will work just fine

Comment: @szczocik My Banner component is present in every parent component. I wonder how can I make just one parent component and still manage pages.

Comment: How do you navigate between the parent components just now? Do you use react-router or just conditional renders?

Comment: @szczocik I use react-router and I have these 3 pages. How can I have 3 pages with just 1 parent? Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own question. I'm not sure this is the best answer but this is what I did:

With react-router I have added this route: /:username/:page

Then I access the page name with props.match.params.page and change the child components depending on it.